# A user defined function which is equivalent of strlen() in C

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, strlen

I want a user defined function which is equivalent to strlen() function in C. In the below program it does the same function as strlen() but it has a limit to it. How can I make it count any length of text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int len(char *);
    char s[20];
    int l;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(s);
    l=len(s);
    printf("length of string is =%d",l);
    getch();
}

int len(char *t)
{
    int count=0;
    while(*t!='\0')
    {
        count++;
        t++;
    }
    return(count);
}
```

Comment: It seems correct to me. What limit are you experiencing?

Comment: Which limit are you referring to? The maximum value of the `int` count variable?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it has a limit to it?

Comment: There's a reason the standard `strlen` uses `size_t` and not `int`...

Comment: The limit can be removed by returning `size_t`.  The code can be speeded up by not using `count` but simply finding the end of the string in `t` and taking the difference between the value of the end and the value passed in (which has to be saved, of course).  The `ptrdiff_t` from the subtraction of the two pointers can be returned safely enough, unless your compiler is unreasonably configured.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can't get it below `O(n)` though. So if you are really concerned about efficiency, you should store the size in a separate variable

Comment: I mean that if I enter a very long string like 400 500 letter count string then the program crashes. What is causing it to crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your "limit" is because you use `gets()` on a buffer of 20 bytes. You will experience issues due to a buffer overflow. Exactly what happens when you do that is not entirely predictable.

If you fix that, I think your function will work as you expect it to. (Read the other people's answers for insight on your length function.)

Comment: i too thing that `get()` is the problem with it. what else should i use to get a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want "any length", you'll need an arbitrary-precision integer library (such as libgmp) for the counter. That's pretty unreasonable, though, since the string will have to fit into your memory, and each character actually has to have an address. That is to say, the length of any string that fits into addressable space can be expressed in a variable of type `size_t` (or `unsigned long int`, I suppose; it'll be something of the same size as the machine's register size).

(Please don't ask about how to form the one-past-the-end pointer of a string that fills out the entire addressable memory.)

Comment: if I enter a very long string like 400 500 letter count string then the program crashes. What is causing it to crash? Even a normal `int` can handle that much. I tried it with `size_t` too but still its crashing.

Comment: Your basic C and understanding of `gets` is flawed. Read the manual, and then stop using `gets` forever and use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its limit is `int` bounds. if you increase it, use `long`. Also, make it unsigned to double the maximum. If you want to be sure that it fit, use `size_t` (which original `strlen` use)

BTW, never use `gets`.

Comment: why not use `gets`? what else should i use then to get a string?

Answer (score 0):

What's the limit you want? Historically a string is terminated by '\0' because its the only way to know where the string ends, otherwise you could actually read the whole stack or heap way past the true length of the string. A method used by other functions to identify the end of a string, **to prevent crash not as a feature** is to stop reading when a value outside the charset is found.

**Edit:** 
Obviously I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(){


    int Length = 0;
    char StrArray[10] = "Hello";

    while (StrArray[Length] != '\0')
    {
        StrArray[Length];
        Length++;
    }

    std::cout << Length;

    std::cin.get();

}
```